# What is causing me to get an error when I try to run grunt build in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, installation, gruntjs

I am trying to build a grunt project. When I insert the command `grunt build` I get this error.

```js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN foundation-libsass-template@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN foundation-libsass-template@0.0.1 No license field.
vagrant@myinteger:/vweb/www.afsb.net$ grunt
/vweb/www.afsb.net/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:106
        ...styles,
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vweb/www.afsb.net/node_modules/grunt-legacy-log-utils/index.js:12:13)
vagrant@myinteger:/vweb/www.afsb.net$
```

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and npm install runs without a problem. H

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you figure out the fix?

Comment: Yes. As it turns out. my local node version was v12 and the version that the project uses is v6. So I had to change to v6 with nvm. `nvm install 6.12.1` and then `nvm use 6.12.1`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it too, it's not working in my case :(